# Numpy 3D array indexing using lists

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing

Suppose I have a numpy array with shape (10, 1000, 1000), and I have three lists, which are supposed to represent the range of indexes of each axis like so:

```
z_range = [0, 5]
y_range = [200, 300]
x_range = [300, 500]
```

I know I can do the following, but it seems rather verbose:

```
arr[z_range[0]:z_range[1], y_range[0]:y_range[1], x_range[0]:x_range[1]]
```

Is there an easier way to slice this particular array using the three lists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't really think of a great way off the top of my head.  There might be a better way using one of Numpy's various indexing tricks.  The simplest I can think of is to manually make `slice()` objects.  The `start:end` syntax actually translates directly to `slice(start, end)` objects.  So you could write:

```
arr[slice(*z_range), slice(*y_range), slice(*x_range)]
```

so that's a least a little nicer but I don't think you really gain much in terms of clarity.

Answer (score 3):

Indexing takes a tuple, so you can just construct your tuple dynamically, using a generator expression:

```
>>> z_range = [0, 3]
>>> y_range = [2, 3]
>>> x_range = [3, 5]
>>> arr = numpy.arange(5*5*5).reshape(5,5,5)
>>> arr[tuple(slice(a, b) for a,b in (x_range, y_range, z_range))]
array([[[ 85,  86,  87]],

       [[110, 111, 112]]])
```